# Using timezone data to workout local user time

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, timezone, utc

we are building a site which will be viewed globally therefore need our dates and times to be timezone aware. I am using the library from https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect to recover the timezone of the user and also whether they observer DST.

What my question was after retrieving this information I am slightly confused what to do with it. We store all information in UTC in the database however when we receive the offset from the library how do we deal with the DST and whether they are from the Northern or Southern hemisphere. Also how do we deal with it on the server side. My thoughts are to handle all dates and times in standard UTC on PHP and then apply the offset once dealing with the views.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: the problem with UTC offsets is that they're NOT enough to identify a timezone. e.g. I'm in Saskatchewan, UTC-6, but we do **NOT** use DST at all.

Comment: hi, I get your situation. Here is an example of the library. http://fiddle.jshell.net/pellepim/CsNcf/show/ Therefore in your case does it identify that you do not observer DST, therefore I would just set the offset to -6 when displaying to you. My problem is when DST is observed and also what northern and southern hemispheres have to do with this!

Comment: that fiddle identifies me as being in America/Guatemala... that's a just a little bit off the mark. If it was 'right', it'd be showing America/Regina.

Comment: @JohnDoe You are un the right way. Just store the dates as UTC in the db and also store the timezone info(GMT offset, or whatever you want..) for each user, and then just apply the timezone info to the date only when you are going to show it in a view.

Comment: I see, I think the library doesn't get geolocation specific however America/Guatemala shares the same -6 UTC offset therefore in my case would be fine as long as the offset delivered is correct.

Comment: @slash28cu That makes sense, I am doing this. My problem is dealing with the DST and hemisphere data. Do I have to take this under consideration when applying the offset?

Comment: @JohnDoe Per my experience you only have to take in consideration the offset, and when you apply the offset to a DateTime object in php for example , php will take care of the DST. Eastern Time(America/New_York) will be UTC-5 or UTC-4(DST). PHP takes care of this automatically.

Comment: @slash28cu: You can get away with considering the offset if the time you are displaying is *now*. Otherwise you also have to care about when daylight saving happens, as then what the offset is changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use jsTimezoneDetect only to guess the time zone of the user. It should be user configurable, both because it can be incorrect, and because the users might want to use another time zone than what he really is in. At least if you have a system where users log in or if you have a system where the users is entering times.

For just temporary visitors that are only viewing things, displaying the time in whatever timezone the user happens to be in should be fine, although you can get things an hour wrong if jsTimezoneDetect guesses the wrong timezone and daylight saving rules are different. If you are relying on jsTimezoneDetect's guess, make sure you clearly display what timezone you are guessing the user is in.

Secondly, you need to convert the UTC dates to the time zone that the user has configured (or jsTimezoneDetect has guessed). You do that by using the zoneinfo/tz/Olsen database (one database, many names) which luckily PHP supports.

Most recipes  to do this in PHP that I can find involves setting the timezone for php as a whole and then formatting the date. Don't do that, that is insane, keep the php's timezone the same as your systems timezone at all times.

Instead there are in the [DateTime library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)'s DateTimeZone objects and support to set the timezone for DateTimes and format them. That's the way to go forward.

So you could do something like this. First create a DateTime object in UTC with the data you get from the database.

```
php > $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
php > echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
2000-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

Then you can convert it to a user timezone:

```
php > $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
php > echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
2000-01-01 13:45:00+13:45
```

Or another one:

```
php > $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('US/Eastern'));
php > echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
1999-12-31 19:00:00-05:00
```

Comment: Was going to suggest the `DateTime` library myself.

Comment: amazing answer, thank you so much for this! Just one little thing, I get all of this except for the database part. If I use the DateTime library to convert to the timezone, is there a need for the database?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Yes, there is, the database has to exist. The DateTime library will use it in the background. Luckily all Unices has this database, so that is all good, what happens on Windows, I don't know.

Comment: ah ok I get it! One last question, I get how to convert the dates to the offsets on the view. However on my models do I have to explicitly set the PHP default timezone to UTC as will it try to use the timezone of the server?

Comment: @JohnDoe: No, you should not have to set the PHP default timezone. It will use your local timezone when you create DateTime objects if you don't specify a timezone, but you can specify it to UTC when creating the DateTime. It does depend on what you get back from the database though, if that is some sort of datetime object it might already have been created with the wrong timezone. That would be a good separate question, in that case. :-)